# unable to figure out C Program crash

Tags: c

While writing a C program for FIR Filter, facing a issue of Program crash. 
Strange thing is during debug mode, nothing strange found. code runs properly.
But crashes during Run - time. IDE being used is Code-Blocks.

Please find code snippet below

main.c

```
#include "common.h"
#include "carrier_NCO_generation.h"
#include "lfsr.h"

int main()
{
    int *nco_out = NULL,*noise_out = NULL,*carrier_gen_I = NULL,*carrier_gen_Q = NULL,*inp_data_I = NULL,*inp_data_Q = NULL;
    int *complex_product_I = NULL,*complex_product_Q = NULL,*FIR_I_Data = NULL,*FIR_Q_Data = NULL;
    int i;

    nco_out             = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    noise_out           = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    carrier_gen_I       = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    carrier_gen_Q       = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    inp_data_I          = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    inp_data_Q          = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    complex_product_I   = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    complex_product_Q   = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    FIR_I_Data          = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));
    FIR_Q_Data          = (int *)malloc(SAMPLES*sizeof(int));

    fileRead(1,SAMPLES,inp_data_I,"rf_sam_i.txt",1);
    fileRead(1,SAMPLES,inp_data_Q,"rf_sam_q.txt",1);


    carrier_NCO(nco_out);
    lfsr(noise_out);
    carrier_generation(nco_out,noise_out,carrier_gen_I,carrier_gen_Q);
    frequency_transpose(carrier_gen_I,carrier_gen_Q,inp_data_I,inp_data_Q,complex_product_I,complex_product_Q);

    fir(complex_product_I,complex_product_Q,FIR_I_Data,FIR_Q_Data);

    /*
    File Record
    */

    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,nco_out,"Carrier_NCO_out.txt",0);
    free(nco_out);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,noise_out,"Carrier_NOISE_out.txt",0);
    free(noise_out);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,carrier_gen_I,"Carrier_gen_I_out.txt",0);
    free(carrier_gen_I);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,carrier_gen_Q,"Carrier_gen_Q_out.txt",0);
    free(carrier_gen_Q);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,complex_product_I,"Freq_Trans_I_out.txt",0);
    free(complex_product_I);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,complex_product_Q,"Freq_Trans_Q_out.txt",0);
    free(complex_product_Q);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,FIR_I_Data,"FIR_I_Data_out.txt",0);
    free(FIR_I_Data);
    fileRecord(1,SAMPLES,FIR_Q_Data,"FIR_Q_Data_out.txt",0);
    free(FIR_Q_Data);

    return 0;
}
```

***The Problem is in FIR Filter, the code is given below***

***FIR.C***

```
#include "fir.h"

void array_multiplication(int *array_data, int coefficients[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        array_data[i] = array_data[i]*coefficients[i];
    }
}

int array_addition(int *array_data, int size)
{
    int i = 0,sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array_data[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

void shift_array_elements(int *array_data, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=size;i>0;i--)
    {
        array_data[i] = array_data[i-1];
    }
}

int symmetrical_rounding_without_bit_extension_8_bit_fir(int number)
{
     int bit_7 = 0,neg_flag = 0,max_negtve = -1048576, max_postve = 1048448;
     int mask_number = 2097024;

     //printf("number at input = %d\n",number);

    if((number < 0)&&(number <= -1048576))
    {
        return max_negtve;
    }
    else if((number > 0)&&(number >= 1048448))
    {
        return max_postve;
    }
    else if(number < 0)
    {
        number = ((number) * (-1));
        neg_flag = 1;

    }

    bit_7 = bitExtracted(number,1,7);

    number = number & mask_number;

    if(bit_7)
    {
        number = number + 128;
    }
    if(neg_flag == 1)
    {
        number = (number * (-1));
    }
    return number;
}

int symmetrical_saturation_on_8_th_bit(int number)
{
    int mask_with = 0x7F,neg_flag = 0,max_negtve = -127, max_postve = 128;

    if((number < 0)&&(number <= max_negtve))
    {
        return max_negtve;
    }
    else if((number > 0)&&(number >= max_postve))
    {
        return max_postve;
    }
    else if(number == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(number < 0)
    {
        number = ((number) * (-1));
        neg_flag = 1;
    }

    number = number & mask_with;
    if(number == 0)
    {
        number = max_postve;
    }
    if(neg_flag == 1)
    {
        number = (number * (-1));
    }
    return (int)number;
}

void fir(int *complex_I_data,int *complex_Q_data,int *I_data_out,int *Q_data_out)
{
    int i = 0,j =0,k = 0,real_sum = 0,imag_sum = 0;
    int *real_part = NULL,*imag_part = NULL,*inp_real_part = NULL,*inp_imag_part = NULL;

    real_part = (int *)malloc(FIR_COEFFICIENT * sizeof(int));
    imag_part = (int *)malloc(FIR_COEFFICIENT * sizeof(int));
    inp_real_part = (int *)malloc(FIR_COEFFICIENT * sizeof(int));
    inp_imag_part = (int *)malloc(FIR_COEFFICIENT * sizeof(int));

    //Initialize to 0.
    for(i =0; i<FIR_COEFFICIENT; i++)
    {
        real_part[i] = 0;
        imag_part[i] = 0;
        inp_real_part[i] = 0;
        inp_imag_part[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i<SAMPLES; i++)
    {

        inp_real_part[0] = complex_I_data[i];
        inp_imag_part[0] = complex_Q_data[i];

        for(j = 0; j<FIR_COEFFICIENT; j++)
        {
            real_part[j] = inp_real_part[j];
            imag_part[j] = inp_imag_part[j];
        }

        //Array multiplication
        array_multiplication(real_part,precumul_fir_coeff_i,FIR_COEFFICIENT);
        array_multiplication(imag_part,precumul_fir_coeff_q,FIR_COEFFICIENT);

        //sum of array elements
        real_sum = array_addition(real_part,FIR_COEFFICIENT);
        imag_sum = array_addition(imag_part,FIR_COEFFICIENT);

        real_sum = symmetrical_rounding_without_bit_extension_8_bit_fir(real_sum);
        imag_sum = symmetrical_rounding_without_bit_extension_8_bit_fir(imag_sum);


        I_data_out[i] = symmetrical_saturation_on_8_th_bit(real_sum);
        Q_data_out[i] = symmetrical_saturation_on_8_th_bit(imag_sum);


        //shifting array elements
        if((i < (SAMPLES-1)))
        {
            //printf("Reached\n");
            shift_array_elements(inp_real_part,FIR_COEFFICIENT);
            shift_array_elements(inp_imag_part,FIR_COEFFICIENT);
        }
    }
    real_part = NULL;
    imag_part = NULL;
    inp_real_part = NULL;
    inp_imag_part = NULL;

    free(real_part);
    free(imag_part);
    free(inp_real_part);
    free(inp_imag_part);
}
```

In FIR.C, Free throws an Error so allocating variables to NULL. Let me know if this is wrong.
Also, SAMPLES = 100.

Please let me know where, i m going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for(i=size;i>0;i--) { array_data[i] = array_data[i-1]; }` I think here you are writing out of bounds.

Comment: Why are you using malloc?

Comment: You can not set your pointers to `NULL` and then free it, this does not make any sense.

Comment: osiris, has knew that null and then free doesn't make any sense, but was getting crashing issue while using free

Comment: How is this related to [tag:embedded]? Don't spam tags.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Check out a tool called [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) it will help detect memory errors such as buffer overflows and not freeing memory etc.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete code, so I am not able to verify, but it looks like the function shift_array_elements is out of bounds:

```
void shift_array_elements(int *array_data, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=size;i>0;i--)
    {
        array_data[i] = array_data[i-1];
    }
}
```

You start from i=size which is out of bounds when called from the fir() function:

```
    if((i < (SAMPLES-1)))
    {
        //printf("Reached\n");
        shift_array_elements(inp_real_part,FIR_COEFFICIENT);
        shift_array_elements(inp_imag_part,FIR_COEFFICIENT);
    }
```

The last element here is `inp_real_part[FIR_COEFFICIENT-1]`, but shift_array_elements will assign to `inp_real_part[FIR_COEFFICIENT]`.

### General tips

- Use the debugger (gdb) to figure out where your program crashes. Compile with `-g -O2` and run the exectuable through gdb to get a stack trace from the crash
- `malloc` will return NULL if allocation fails. Always check the returned value before you proceed when using `malloc/free`.